# Open YouTube video in Fancybox jQuery

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox

Can I open YouTube video in Fancybox.

I have a list of YouTube videos links, for ex:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PvbqV8W96D0" class="more">Play</a>
```

and Fancybox :

```
$("a.more").fancybox({
                    'titleShow'     : false,
                    'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                    'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
        });
```

I don't want to create for each video new embed object.

Is there some plug in, or a other way to do that ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### THIS IS BROKEN, SEE EDIT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("a.more").fancybox({
                    'titleShow'     : false,
                    'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                    'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
            'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type'      : 'swf',
            'swf'       : {'wmode':'transparent','allowfullscreen':'true'}
        });
</script>
```

This way if the user javascript is enabled it opens a fancybox with the youtube embed video, if javascript is disabled it opens the video's youtube page. If you want you can add

```
target="_blank"
```

to each of your links, it won't validate on most doctypes, but it will open the link in a new window if fancybox doesn't pick it up.

## EDIT

`this`, above, isn't referenced correctly, so the code won't find `href` under `this`. You have to call it like this:

```
$("a.more").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
            'padding'       : 0,
            'autoScale'     : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
            'transitionOut' : 'none',
            'title'         : this.title,
            'width'     : 680,
            'height'        : 495,
            'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type'          : 'swf',
            'swf'           : {
                 'wmode'        : 'transparent',
                'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
            }
        });

    return false;
});
```

as covered at http://fancybox.net/blog #4, replicated above

Comment: The `this` reference here is not the `a` element. Therefore, `this.href` is undefined.

Comment: @jsumners: indeed doesn't work ... this.href isn't defined ... it's not a listener you are defining there.

Comment: The reason this version doesn't work verbatim is because you're missing the click event first. The example on the blog has the fancybox call wrapped inside of a click call, which is why you get the anchor when referring to 'this'.

Comment: I had to add the `event.preventDefault();` code into my function to get it to work.

Answer (score 22):

I started by using the answers here, but modified it to use YouTube's new `iframe` embedding...

```
$('a.more').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.fancybox({
        'type' : 'iframe',
        // hide the related video suggestions and autoplay the video
        'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp('watch\\?v=', 'i'), 'embed/') + '?rel=0&autoplay=1',
        'overlayShow' : true,
        'centerOnScroll' : true,
        'speedIn' : 100,
        'speedOut' : 50,
        'width' : 640,
        'height' : 480
    });
});
```

Comment: I find this method better as the swf version has issues displaying the right size on an iPhone - they both have the same issue of fancybox being too hight, but the iFrame version fills the height with the video, but the swf scales it down.

Answer (score 21):

```
$("a.more").click(function() {
                 $.fancybox({
                  'padding'             : 0,
                  'autoScale'   : false,
                  'transitionIn'        : 'none',
                  'transitionOut'       : 'none',
                  'title'               : this.title,
                  'width'               : 680,
                  'height'              : 495,
                  'href'                : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
                  'type'                : 'swf',    // <--add a comma here
                  'swf'                 : {'allowfullscreen':'true'} // <-- flashvars here
                  });
                 return false;

            });
```

Answer (score 5):

If you wanna add autoplay function to it. Simply replace

```
this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
```

with

```
this.href = this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/') + '&autoplay=1',
```

also you can do the same with vimeo

```
this.href.replace(new RegExp("([0-9])","i"),'moogaloop.swf?clip_id=$1'),
```

with

```
this.href = this.href.replace(new RegExp("([0-9])","i"),'moogaloop.swf?clip_id=$1') + '&autoplay=1',
```

Answer (score 2):

This has a regular expression so it's easier to just copy and paste the youtube url. Is great for when you use a CMS for clients.

```
/*fancybox yt video*/
$(".fancybox-video").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({

    padding: 0,
        'autoScale'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'title'         : this.title,
        'width'         : 795,
        'height'        : 447,
        'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch.*v=","i"), "v/"),
        'type'          : 'swf',
        'swf'           : {
        'wmode'             : 'transparent',
        'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
         }

    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanx, Alexander!

And to set the fancy-close button above the youtube's flash-content add 'wmode' to 'swf' parameters:

```
'swf': {'allowfullscreen':'true', 'wmode':'transparent'}
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to do anything differently