# How do I show youtube embeds in Fancybox?

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox

I'm trying to use fancybox to show an embedded youtube video. I found a great solution here (http://chadly.net/post/2009/01/29/Lightbox-for-YouTube-Videos.aspx), but the problem is that it uses a modified version of fancybox that isn't compatible with the fancybox that I currently have on my site. How do I use this version? Or must something be created from scratch?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542252/open-youtube-video-in-fancybox-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Use [Colorbox](http://www.colorpowered.com/colorbox/)

Check [examples](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html) one of them shows an embedded youtube video.