# Can't figure out how to play a Youtube Playlist using Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is it possible to use FancyBox to display a succession of Youtube videos (using a Youtube playlist defined at the end of an url). Reason why I asked is that FancyBox only takes the actual video location and nothing else so if there were any arguments after the Youtube url say, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wmhfn3mgWUI&feature=bf_prev&list=ULBn59FJ4HrmU it would only display the very first video in that list or rather http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wmhfn3mgWUI. Any thoughts? This is what I have for the JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
                type : 'swf',
        helpers : {
            media : {}
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is how I'm calling it:

```
<a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wmhfn3mgWUI&amp;feature=bf_prev&amp;list=ULBn59FJ4HrmU">clicking here</a>.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create simple html page with iframed playlist (you can get the code [here](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUHzIO0agtCQEsTxUcahZgjQ&feature=plcp) clicking the 'share' button).

Then, set the fancybox as iframe type (or ajax, both should work) linking to your new page.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542252/open-youtube-video-in-fancybox-jquery?rq=1), it has been asked before and it is explained in depth together with links with additional resources.