# Fancybox Youtube video returning 'href' error

Tags: jquery, video, youtube, fancybox

I am trying to make Youtube videos on this webpage( http://medicalfutures.co.uk.s156312.gridserver.com/2011.php) load using Fancybox but every time I press the link, nothing happens and in my error console on Chrome I get the message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined"

Any ideas?

EDIT:

The video link is quite near the top of the page ("Watch the video here")

Comment: First thing, try upgrading your fancybox js (from your current v2.0.3 to 2.1.3) and css files that seem to be outdated (your fancybox css file is actually for a v1.3.x) ... then will see

Comment: You may wish to check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542252/open-youtube-video-in-fancybox-jquery Good luck!

Comment: I looked at that link and tried the code but it did the same thing :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh the problem was the YouTube link - I had an embedded link which doesn't work